# How to change Lightroom's folder organization

Tags: lightroom, file-management

In my lightroom library I organize my photos in the following way:

-> Photos

-----> year.month.day.CountryCode.City.Occasion

Example:

-> Photos

--->   2010.11.07.NZ.Wellington.My_Birthday

--->   2010.12.25.NZ.Wellington.Xmas

Since you can imagine the huge number of folders under "photos", I am trying to put the year under photos, and then all folders from that year under that. Which might still be plenty, but I do not want to have several levels of folders to organize my photos.

Is there a way to automate this operation so that I do not need to manually move each folder into another one?

Comment: It might be possible to automate this, but I'd argue that it's time/effort spent on something you already have covered w/ the camera's data and some basic Lightroom keywording.  The EXIF data (searchable) contains the photo's date, and if you apply keywords for the country, city, and event when you do the Lightroom import, you're set.  Even if you migrate away from Lightroom you can export this metadata.  This level of detail in your folder structure seems like duplicated work.

Answer (score 1):

In Lightroom Import there is a way to set the import options to import into specific folders as you outlined. You may also want to consider nested folders which it does as one of the defaults. For instance my settings is that it is imported as:

- Year

  - Month

    - Day

This setting is done on import, so moving forward that is one solution. I then put the events and other descriptions into the keywords. That way I can search for time period or event. So for instance I can search for Birthday, and it will find all the Birthdays which I can then filter down to just the specific one either by what folder I am looking in or through other search terms.

I believe that if one imports from an existing catalog to a new catalog that the images can be moved to the folder structure if desired.

Sorry, I am backing up the drive at the moment or I would test it out for you.